# Page number index

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a `vendor`, `category` and `page`.  I need to create an index (like you have in a catalog) based on this table.

I can do this in Excel by looping through the rows and if the vendor and the category are the same as the row above, the new page is added to the end of the cell above it:

```
Tim's Company      Code     120
Tim's Company      Code     122
```

would result in

```
Tim's Company      Code     120,122
```

Excel is fine when I am dealing with under a 1000 rows.  I am up in the 12K area here.  It would take forever.  Plus, I end up with some instances of the page repeating which I don't want.  In `SQL` I can get rid of the duplicates up front, I am not sure how to do the concatenation on the page.  Would I be better off doing this in `SSRS`? or would a view generate the results as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: **[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6c29/3)**

```
SELECT t1.Vendor,t1.Category,
       csvPages = REPLACE( (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),Page) AS [data()]
                            FROM mytable t2
                            WHERE t2.Vendor = t1.Vendor AND 
                                  t2.Category = t1.Category
                            ORDER BY t2.Vendor
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                           ), ' ', ',')
FROM mytable t1
GROUP BY t1.Vendor,t1.Category ;
```

Comment: I only have one table t1 what is t2?

Comment: I am also using only one table called mytable. t1, t2 are `Table Aliases` for the same table. Just replace mytable with your table name. MSDN Link for Table Aliases: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(vendor varchar(32), category varchar(32), page int);

INSERT @x VALUES
('Tim''s Company','Code',120),
('Tim''s Company','Code',122);

SELECT vendor, category, pages = STUFF((
  SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(11), page)
  FROM @x AS x2
  WHERE x2.vendor = x.vendor AND x2.category = x.category
  ORDER BY page
  FOR XML PATH(''), 
  TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM @x AS x
GROUP BY vendor, category;
```

Comment: I don't get the second table.  Do I have to duplicate the table to cause this to work?

Comment: Yes, it's essentially a self-join, but using a correlated subquery. If this doesn't work out performance-wise due to the amount of data, consider doing this elsewhere (like in C#).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that joins all values to a scalar value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getPages]
(
    @Vendor varchar(100),
    @Category varchar(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Pages VARCHAR(8000) 
    SELECT @Pages = COALESCE(@Pages + ',','') +  CAST(TN.Page AS VARCHAR)
    FROM dbo.TableName TN
    WHERE TN.Vendor=@Vendor AND TN.Category=@Category
    ORDER BY TN.Page
    RETURN @Pages
END
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
SELECT Vendor, Category, 
       Pages=dbo.getPages(Vendor,Category)
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY Vendor, Category
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/406c8/1/0)</kbd>

```
VENDOR          CATEGORY        PAGES
Tims Company    Code            120,122
```